# keep the menu intact when the window is zoomed or for different resolutions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is my vertical navigation fixed on top of the window,want that if users zoom the window or opened on different resolutions, if decreases the font so that it does not go to next line and all the items are visible ?

```
<ul id="navmenu" class="drop">

  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Updates</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Assignment</a> </li>
  <li><a href="#">Project</a></li>  
  <li><a href="#">Practice</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Shedule</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Fee</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Export</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Account</a> </li>

</ul>



ul#navmenu {margin: 0 0 0 0%;}
ul.drop a { display:block; color:white; text-decoration:none;}
ul.drop, ul.drop li, ul.drop ul { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; color: #fff; }
ul.drop { position: relative; z-index: 60; float: left; }
ul.drop li { float: left; vertical-align: middle; }
ul.drop li.hover, ul.drop li:hover { position: relative; z-index: 70; cursor: default; }
ul.drop ul { width:6em; visibility: hidden; padding: 2px 1px;  position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0; z-index: 65; }
ul.drop ul li { float: none; }
ul.drop ul ul { top: -2px; left: 100%; }
ul.drop li:hover > ul { visibility: visible ; }
```

Comment: [What have you tried ?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: i added overflow: hidden ; but the elements which are at corner are crossing the window !....want that they should adjust for different resolutions ?

Comment: to my knowledge only mozilla offer the zoom text only option & i don't think many user use it; but if you set your width & padding & position & margin in em; even in zoom text only mode those will be zoomed as well therefore not breaking the layout

Comment: thanks but how to deal with different resolutions ?